Why do I get No buffer space available when trying to use a gre tunnel?
I am trying to tunnel from a vps to another vps via ipv6 and this is my /etc/rc.local
sudo ip -6 tunnel add gre1 mode ip6gre local *LOCALIPV6* remote *REMOTEIPV6* ttl 255
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.2/30 dev gre1
sudo ip link set gre1 up

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/30 ! -o gre+ -j SNAT --to-source *LOCALIPV4*



exit 0

However I get
add tunnel "ip6gre0" failed: No buffer space available
RTNETLINK answers: File exists

when running bash /etc/rc.local
Where did I go wrong?
